# Showing an overlay view under the status bar in AccessibilityService on Pie

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, accessibilityservice

i am trying to show a full screen view overlay view under status bar in `AccessibilityService` using `WindowManager` by using these flags.

```
 params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS 
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE ,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

behaviour on android O or lesser
[image]

behaviour on android P or greater
[image]

before android-P (API-28) it's showing under status bar but in API >=28 its showing above the status bar can someone tell me the problem or is there new flag?

Comment: Here also, same problem only in Android O.

Comment: @BrowJri I have tested on LG v20 with android O it's showing under status bar did you found any solution?

Comment: still without solution :-(

Answer (score 2):

Accessibility overlays are supposed to be on top of everything, so I would say the bug is in O or lesser.

I've seen this behavior vary from device to device, and OEM to OEM. So it may not be the Android version that's causing the variation.